# @Transactional and GenericApplicationContext don't work together

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I'm using @Transactional and transaction management by annotation (tx:annotation-driven...). I have problem when I'm using GenericApplicationContext to create application context and get some beans from it:

```
GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();

// Load beans definitions 
XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource(CONTEXT_PATH));

// Register the datasource 
ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(CONTEXT_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME, dataSource);

// Get the service
ServiceInterface service = (ServiceInterface) ctx.getBean("service");
```

I've got the instance of ServiceInterface but I want to have the proxy which contains information about transactions.

Could you explain me what I've missed?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How do you configure transactions?

Comment: I'm using @Transactional annotation on service and dao classes and have <tx:annotation-driven> in configuration xml. In code showed above I call for the bean "service" and get it, but the instance of class, but I need proxy with TransactionInterceptor. How can I proceed Transactional annotation after creating the context in way which I showed?

Comment: Basically my problem is very similar to: http://forum.springsource.org/showth...-via-a-factory

I want to have transactions on beans created by bean factory. How to proceed transaction annotation after getting bean from bean factory?

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. You don't need to shout "SOLVED" in titles nor to edit the answer into the question itself. Just post a normal answer --when the time allows it-- and then mark it accepted. It'll appear as "solved" in the listing and search. I rolledback your change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need to call ctx.refresh() before ctx.getBean(). Then the BeanPostProcessors will be invoked.